# Jquery mobile 1.2 and PhoneGap 2.2.0 pages transition flickering

Tags: jquery, iphone, cordova, jquery-mobile, ios6

In doing a project with JqueryMobile 1.2 and PhoneGap/Cordova 2.2.0 and i have a problem with page transition, when i use 
data-transition= slide on an element it works very slow' and if i use data-transition= none  i get a black flickring between screens, im working on iphone 4 with IOS 6.1' i have tried all the answers i found hear but nothing works and i still get black flickring when i navigate with data-transition="none"

i hope someone can help me' hear is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> jQuery Mobile Boilerplate - Collapsibles Content</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- jQuery Mobile CSS bits -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />

    <!-- if you have a custom theme, add it here -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="themes/jQuery-Mobile-Boilerplate.css" />

    <!-- Custom css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />

    <!-- Javascript includes -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2-min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/mobileinit.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/application.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
    <div data-role="page">

        <div data-role="header">
            <a href="../index.html" data-icon="home">Home</a>
            <h1>Collapsible Content</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">




<h2>Collapsible Content Blocks</h2>

<div data-role="collapsible">
    <h3>Content header</h3>
    <p>I'm the content that shows/hides when you click the header just above me.</p>
</div>

<h2>Default to open</h2>

<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
    <h3>Content header</h3>
    <p>I'm the content that shows/hides when you click the header just above me.</p>
</div>

<h2>Themed</h2>

<div data-role="collapsible" data-content-theme="c">
    <h3>Content header</h3>
    <p>I'm the content that shows/hides when you click the header just above me.</p>
</div>

<h2>Themed - content only</h2>

<div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="e" >
    <h3>Content header</h3>
    <p>I'm the content that shows/hides when you click the header just above me.</p>
</div>

<h2>Nested Collapsibles</h2>

<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-theme="e" data-content-theme="c">
    <h3>Outer header</h3>
    <p>I'm the content inside the main collapsible.</p>

    <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="c" data-content-theme="c">
        <h3>I'm a nested collapsible with a child collapsible</h3>
        <p>I'm a child collapsible.</p>
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="d" data-content-theme="d">
            <h3>Nested inside again.</h3>
            <p>Three levels deep now.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="collapsible" data-content-theme="c">
        <h3>Collapsed list</h3>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d">
            <li><a href="index.html">red</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">blue</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">yellow</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /section 3 -->
</div>



        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="c">
            <p>&copy; 2012 - jQuery Mobile Boilerplate</p>
        </div>  

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here, I come with the solution........

check out


http://stackoverflow.com/a/14986718/1356174

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try putting this in your JS:

```
  $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none'; 
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;  
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, i did put it but it didn't help

Comment: this really works and one need to add this after including jquery, that is where I added this code and it worked, but also did someother things like making hardware accelerated false in android manifest. No need to change viewport options

Answer (score 5):

*This is my first post, so I don't have enough reputation  to comment, but I will do my best to provide some kind of answer instead.*

I am struggling with the same issue. It seems to me that it is an iOS 6 issue, e.g there is no flickering in iOS 5 and in my case Android 2.2+ . I use `$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';`.

**Attempt to Answer:**
Check to see if you have overflow-x:hidden in your styles for your pages. The flicker disappeared when I removed "overflow-x:hidden" in my styles for the pages I wanted to navigate between.

**Extra info:**
Unfortunately, in my case, since I need pages to be native scrollable, "overflow-x:hidden" is necessary for the fixed-position headers and footers to stay fixed without the page to get the iOS Webkit browser rubber band effect.

If you change the background color of your page, to for example red, you will probably see the red color flickering instead of the black color. That's how it is for me at least. And that should mean that it is a page background z-index issue. JQuery Mobile has had issues with z-index and flickering in earlier releases.

One other thing that I tried to do is to remove the overflow-x:hidden with `$("#myPage").css('overflow-x', "");` from the current page before calling `$.mobile.changePage([...]);` and to the page I am navigating to. Then on the pageshow event I put back overflow-x with `$("page).css('overflow-x', "hidden");`. But that did not resolve the issue. I had no rubber band effect, but the background was still popping up.

I hope this answer and extra info can help anyone looking into this new issue with JQuery Mobile 1.2.0 on iOS 6 using for example Phonegap/Cordova.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, i didn't tested all the possibilities you suggested to me however it is probably some thing in my css file, ill keep looking for it and will update hear

Comment: i did it on a new project and it worked fine so something i my css, working on it

Answer (score 1):

There are no current solution to this problem at the current moment.

I even read that some IOS also have this problem.

I know on android its even worse.  However im not a "MAC" user, so i cant test this out a 100%.  Even though i know that Iphone users shouldent have this problem to much though.

*Android + Jquery Mobile just have this problem atm.*

Page Transitions dosent work on android as intended, there are page flickerings, double blinks and so on.  Even if you turn off transitions you will still get the old "blink" that a website will make from the older days.

There are some "who reported they have fixed it 50%", but these solutions are very individuel, and dosent work for all at all.

I dont feel i want to give you half answers, i rather want to tell you that Jquery Mobile is under development, and if i where you, i would wait it out :)

I hope my answer gave you the thoughts you needed :)